# Facebook Login Button not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to login facebook with javascript on localhost.I used http://localhost:port/ for site url and localhost for App Domains in my last project and it's totally fine.Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work now.I'm now using test app.It shows "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.".Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps
- Select your app
- add http://localhost:port to `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`

Comment: Thanks for your attention.I can't find Valid OAuth redirect URIs in both basic and advanced setting.

Comment: it is under the "PRODUCTS" -> "Facebook Login" -> "Settings" section

Comment: You may need to add a platform first (Website), then the settings will be for that platform.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.Error message has changed.It shows "App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.".What should I do next?

Comment: 1) go to Settings ->Basic -> Contact Email

. Type your email address here   2)

G o to App Review page.

 Make your app public


If I helped you, please upvote and accept :)

Comment: I don't have App Review page on test app.When I switch on real app and make app public.It shows the old error message again :(.I think this is because I am using bracket live preview which host my web page on "127.0.0.1:53261/facebook.html"(with Chrome).When I try to manually access with "file://mypath/facebook.html" , facebook login button is not showing.What should I do next?

Comment: been looking over an hour for this solution..seems nothing works to have login on localhost

Answer (score 1):

That was my mistake.I was using bracket IDE and it's live preview runs my app on port 53261.I change my web page location to PHP built in server and add "http://localhost:port" to Valid OAuth redirect URIs.It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook locks-down their login based on the referrer URL.  Since the rerefer is going to be http://localhost if you're testing localy, the widget will not load.

However, in the Facebook App settings you will find a place to put the site URL.

After entering the URL for the site, edit your Hosts file and add:

```
127.0.0.1    theurlyousetatfacebook.com
```

Then access the site over that URL.  The only way the Facebook Login widget will work is if the URL settings on Facebook match the URL you are accessing the site over.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.I added my host file to "127.0.0.1       myfacebookapp" and add site url to "http://myfacebookapp.com/" .But it still doesn't work.

Comment: The hosts file will need "myfacebookapp.com".  Also, you will need to access the site via the new url, ie "http://myfacebookapp.com:PORT"

Comment: Hosts file is edited like this "127.0.0.1       myfacebookapp.com".And it still doesn't work.I just found out that I am now using bracket live preview which host my web page on "http://127.0.0.1:53261/facebook.html"(with Chrome).When I try to manually access with "file://mypath/facebook.html" , facebook login button is not showing.What should I do next?